# How to to prevent Spring to create an "abstract" generic type repository that is just to be extended?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, repository

If I want to do something like this:

```
public interface LongIdRepo<T> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, Long> {}
```

because I would like to extend it like:

```
public interface MyRepo extends LongIdRepo<My> {}
```

it is not possible because :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'longIdRepo': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   managed type: class java.lang.Object

Is there some way to make Spring to ignore the LongIdRepo bean creation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this [@NoRepositoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/NoRepositoryBean.html) annotation

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface LongIdRepo<T> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, Long> {}
```

Comment: Obviously ;) Thanks.